# Detect unused imports in visual studio code for python 3?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am subscribing to this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/43) about warning unused imports for python in visual studio code.

I am not particular about whether it's squiggle or gray out. But I am not certain if this feature is available based on the discussion or there's a workaround using a linter.

I am okay either way so long some detection is available.

I am using pylint as linter for now. Would be okay to use other linter so long I can detect unused imports.

And I do not want to auto remove unused imports.

This is what I see despite turning on pylint. I have purposely added an unused import. And I am not seeing any problems in this file.

[image]

Comment: what theme is that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Update/create VSCode user settings

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--enable=W0614"
]
```

this works for me in Python 3.6.7 / 3.6.8

Comment: Thanks this worked! Why is it not default and needs to be enabled?

Comment: enabling W0614 didn't work for me, what did was to enable W0611

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: If you're curious where the User Settings are you can press `CMD/CTRL + SHIFT + P` and then type "settings.json" to bring it up.

Comment: W0614 is an unused wildcard import, W0611 is the more general unused import

Answer (score 7):

The Python extension for VS Code does not support warning about unused imports in its language server yet. But if you want Pylint to warn you, create a `.pylintrc` and and turn on the [`W0611` warning](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0611).

Comment: Thanks I turned it on but to no avail. I have both pep8 and Pylint on in the workspace settings for vs code

Comment: Did you check you get the warning when running the linters manually from the terminal?

Comment: Oh so it doesn't auto show up in the vs code itself? I have added a screenshot as well.

Comment: If the linters tell us there's something to warn about then we show the warning. My point is that if the linters won't tell you when run manually then the extension won't warn you either. Basically the extension just executes the linters on your behalf and parses the output; nothing fancy, which typically means that if we don't show it then the linter didn't report it.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio code has released a new feature last year in [April](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23) in 2018 which allow users to change their settings to remove `unused imports` automatically on save. Personally I have tried to configure both **JavaScript** and **TypeScript** and it works great out of box, so I'll assume it should also work for **Python** since you can enable/disable by using the language setting, please try updating your `setting.json` file with the following new changes:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[python]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
    }
},
```

Hopefully this could work on your Python project! Good luck!

Comment: To me this only sorts the imports, but doesn't remove unused ones.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one:

- install pylance extension
- user/workSpace setting `languageServer`

  ```
  {
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance"
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It only highlights the unused imports but not automatically removes them.

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
"--enable=W0614"],
"[python]": {
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.organizeImports": true
}},
```

Version: 1.37.1 (user setup)
Date: 2019-08-15T16:17:55.855Z
Electron: 4.2.7
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.16299

Comment: My imports are sorted, but I don't see any highlight of unused import

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the autoflake plugin (https://github.com/PyCQA/autoflake) in VSCode, and added the shortcut `CTRL + SHIFT + i`. Whenever I press `CTRL + SHIFT + i`, unused imports are removed.

After installing autoflake, you cand find it pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+p` on VSCode, then typing **autoflake**. You can then set up the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem using python 3.8 interpreter and nothing from above answers helped.

What worked for me was installing the Pylint plugin (v2023.10.1). It now just underlines in yellow the unused imports.