How to list all packages that are being used in python script?
I want to check all the packages that are being used by my python script. I have a list of imports at the top of the script, but I'm not sure if those packages are actually getting used. So I want to check, of all the commands/functions I am using within by script, which of my imports are being used.
For example in the sample below I am only using the pandas package but I am importing numpy as well:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file.csv")

I want to be able to get back a result of just pandas since that is the only package that is getting used.
All the solutions I've seen will just get all the packages that are imported.

usually called unused imports. prior discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53357649/detect-unused-imports-in-visual-studio-code-for-python-3

Use vulture to find unused imports. Install it:
pip install vulture
vulture your_script.py

